# SQLServer how to convert single row values in to multiple rows with each property as separat

Tags: sql-server-2017

I have a user defined type which is passed to my sql stored procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[LearningDelivery] AS TABLE(
    [LearnAimRef]       NVARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
    [AimType]           INT             NOT NULL,
    [AimSeqNumber]      INT             NOT NULL,
);
```

i have a table with structure as below. I want to match join the type name from the above definition into the ElementName column of the FieldDefinitation table and insert separate insert statements. can anyone help me how to achieve this?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LearningAimData]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [LearnerId] INT NOT NULL,
    [FieldId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Data] VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
)
```

I want to insert each type i.e LearnAimRef , AimType as individual row values in the LearningAimData.
I have a lookup table for [FieldId]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FieldDefinition]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [FieldId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [ElementName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm completely confused: your Type and table are completely different. Can you [edit] and give sample input data for the parameter, and expected output into the table

Comment: As @Charlieface says; can you please post some sample data, as your explanation above does not really say anything.